# How to combine 2 select result with same ID to right in single record

Tags: sql

if the query :

```
select 1 'id member',2 'material total'

select 1 'id member',4 'cash total'
```

Result:

```
id member   material total
----------- --------------
1           2

id member   cash total
----------- -----------
1           4
```

I want join that result. Desired Result:

```
id member  | material total | cash total
-----------| -------------- |-----------
1          | 2              |          4
```

Comment: select 1 'id member',2 'material total',4 'cash total'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given example, the other answer by SonalPM is correct.

However, as a general solution where your data is not *hard coded*, use SQL **JOIN**.
In this case, you can join the two result sets based on `id member`

e.g.

```
SELECT x.id_member, x.mat_total, y.cash_total
FROM 
  (SELECT 1 `id_member`, 2 `mat_total`) x,
  (SELECT 1 `id_member`, 4 `cash_total`) y 
WHERE x.id_member = y.id_member
```

Comment: You are Welcome. If this is helpful/correct, please accept this as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a join like this:

```
SELECT a.idm,
       a.mat,
       b.cash
FROM (SELECT 1 `idm`, 2 `mat`) a
  JOIN (SELECT 1 `idm`, 4 `cash`) b ON a.idm = b.idm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try join:

```
SELECT q1.id_member, q1.material_total, q2.cash_total
FROM (SELECT 1 'id_member',2 'material_total') AS q1
JOIN (SELECT 1 'id_member',4 'cash_total') AS q2
ON q1.id_member = q2.id_member
```